# Get latest builds for each branche in Drone.io

Tags: drone.io

IS there a way to retrieve the latest builds for each branch in drone.io..
Travis-ci support this :

api GET /repos/{repository.id}/branches
and show this in its UI:

https://travis-ci.org/{user}/{repository}/branches

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve information about builds and then filter out by branch in your code.

`https://drone.domain.com/api/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/builds`

Replace with your host, user and repo.

https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/master/router/router.go#L72

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the latest build for a single branch, you can filter it using [conditions](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/conditions/).

Example (for branch `develop`):

```
https://drone.domain.com/api/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/builds?branch=develop
```